# vue.js sum of keys after applying filterBy

Tags: javascript, vue.js

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <form id="search">
    Filter <input name="query" v-model="filterQuery">
  </form>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="client in clients | filterBy filterQuery">
      <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ client.coins }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <b>Total Coins: ???</b>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      title: "Demo app",
      clients: [
        {name: "client X",  coins:  5},
        {name: "client Y",  coins: 10},
        {name: "client Z",  coins:  3},
        {name: "client Z2", coins: 12}
      ]
  }
});
```

**[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9tuxy8h1/3/)**

I am new to `vue.js` and struggling to find a right way of making 'Total Coins' value.

For example : Total sum of coins is equal '30', so when i enter the letter "z" in to the filter box, the filter is applied, "Client Z" and "Client Z2" only should be visible and the total of coins would be equal '15'.

What is the right way to do it in `vue.js` ?

What have i done before asking ?

- I have done this using listener on `filterQuery` change , but this is not efficient as more filters may be added.
- Have tried to add `v-model` to the `v-for` loop so i can get filtered results in a dedicated variable, but this does not seem to update the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this

https://jsfiddle.net/f5d16skc/

```
computed: {
    filteredClients: function () {
    return this.clients.filter(c => c.name.indexOf(this.query) !== -1)
  },
  totalCoins: function () {
    return this.filteredClients.reduce((a, b) => a + b.coins, 0)
  }
}
```

Remember: never use filters in `v-for`! It's deprecated.

Comment: I have been following the [grid-component](http://012.vuejs.org/examples/grid-component.html) tutorial , never seen a deprecation warning ...

Comment: You are free to make a pull request ;) but seriously, it's deprecated all over the place. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2756

Comment: I just realized you are using the 0.X version. We are now reaching version 2.0, why would you use such an old version?